# Freya - How to define a Uri Template with Optional Query String Parameters

Tags: f#, freya

I am using the [Freya web stack](https://github.com/freya-fs/freya) to build a REST API and am having trouble defining the *URI Template* for a route.

I have defined a *Uri Template* that looks like this:

```
"/{store}/{partition}{?date}"
```

Now the **Freya** router matches this *Uri Template* with the following urls:

```
http://localhost/a/1?date=2015
http://localhost/b/3?date=2013
```

However, if I omit the query string then the *Uri Template* no longer matches the url. For example, the following urls are not matched by the template:

```
http://localhost/a/1
http://localhost/b/3
```

How do I define a *Uri Template* using **Freya** with optional query string parameters?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, so I didn't find exactly the answer I was looking for but did find a way to achieve the result I wanted. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find anything in the source code of **Freya** that suggests query string parameters can be defined as optional in a *Uri Template*.

However, I can define two *routes* can be defined with two separate  *Uri Templates* pointing to the same *freyaMachine*.

I ended up with two routes like this:

```
let routes =
    freyaRouter {
        route (Methods [GET]) "/{store}/{partition}" myMachine
        route (Methods [GET]) "/{store}/{partition}{?date}" myMachine
    } |> FreyaRouter.FreyaPipeline
```